# Implementing replace for ContentProviderOperation

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

I'm currently using `SQLiteDatabase.replace` to update certain rows in my database. I'm migrating to a ContentProvider and I'm trying to replace these statements with an equivalent `ContentProviderOperation`. There are factory methods for update, delete, and insert, but there's no `newReplace`. I'm guessing that's because the documentation says that `SQLiteDatabase.replace` is a convenience method which replaces the row only if the primary key matches, else it adds a new one. However, I don't understand what's actually going on under the hood. I assume if I just did a `delete` then `insert` it would be less efficient than a `replace`, is that correct?

How do I mimic the functionality of `SQLiteDatabase.replace` using `ContentProviderOperation`?

Answer (score 0):

This looks promising (at least for my use case): [Android Contentprovider - update within an insert method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4285266/android-contentprovider-update-within-an-insert-method). Basically I need to change `insert()` in my ContentProvider to do an update if it fails.